# Proof of Leibniz Rule for formal derivatives

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-writing

Is there a method to prove Leibniz's Rule, in the context of formal derivatives of polynomials over Finite Fields?

If I have two polynomials $a(x), b(x) \in GF(q)[x]$, How can I prove that $D(a(x)b(x)) = a(x)D(b(x)) + D(a(x))b(x)$

The [Wikipedia page for formal derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_derivative#Properties) indicates that this can be proven. However, it does not reference any proofs and I could not find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Distribution of multiplication over addition, and linearity of the formal derivative, means you can start with monomials and build from there.